# Find specific value in a large json file

Tags: json, filter

I've a simple json array similar to the below. I'd like to find the record that contain a matching value, say for example name == jack.

```
{
  "data": [
  {
    "Record": {
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Jack",
        "age": "38",
        "description": "1234",
        }
      }
    }  
  ]
}
```

Below python code works but it is very slow. Is there any way to get the results quicker?

```
with open('records.json') as f:
    input_dict = json.load(f)
    input_var = input_dict["data"]        

for i in input_var:
    if i["Record"]["attributes"]["name"] == "Jack":
        print(i["Record"]["attributes"])
        break
```

Comment: JSON looks invalid here but assuming there's a closing brace, why not iterate over `data` instead of the keys in the outer dict? I'm a bit confused on how this loop is working.

Comment: thanks. code updated